# Shift addplot on x axis to match end of another plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Hello and happy new year,

I am trying to create a continuous plot made of two different functions. Altough I am able to calculate and plot both of them correctly, I am not able to make the second function start on the end of the first one:

[image]

Both functions are calculated starting at a time of 0, but the red line should start at the end of the blue line, so it needs to be shifted to 0.2ns. I have tried using `shift={(0.2,0)}` on the second plot, but the data appears far away.

Thanks in advance :)

PS: I know that the red line appears on 0 because its domain is defined from 0 to 3.

My tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[class=IEEEtran]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

%- Declare parameters
\usetikzlibrary{math} % For computations. Variables must be declared in a tikzmath environment but can be used outside (almost anywhere)
\tikzmath{
    \Qfactor = 500; % Quality factor 
    \f0 =230; % Freq in GHz 
    \TimeConst = \Qfactor/(pi*\f0);
    \finalCharge = exp(-2*0.2/\TimeConst)-1; % Initial value for ringing tail
} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xmin=0, xmax=3,
        ymin=-30, ymax=5,
        ytick = {-30,-25,-20,-15,-10,-5,0,5},
        ylabel = { Normalized power (dB)},
        xlabel = {Time (ns)},
        width=3.15in,
        height=2.15in,
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks, domain=0:0.2,samples = 10] plot (\x, {10*log10(abs(exp(-2*\x/\TimeConst)-1))});
    % PLOT TO SHIFT:
    \addplot+[no marks, domain=0:3,samples = 50] plot (\x, {10*log10(abs(\finalCharge*exp(-2*\x/\TimeConst)))});   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by simple math:

```tex
\documentclass[class=IEEEtran]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

%- Declare parameters
\usetikzlibrary{math} % For computations. Variables must be declared in a tikzmath environment but can be used outside (almost anywhere)
\tikzmath{
    \Qfactor = 500; % Quality factor 
    \f0 =230; % Freq in GHz 
    \TimeConst = \Qfactor/(pi*\f0);
    \finalCharge = exp(-2*0.2/\TimeConst)-1; % Initial value for ringing tail
} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = left,
        xmin=0, xmax=3,
        ymin=-30, ymax=5,
        ytick = {-30,-25,-20,-15,-10,-5,0,5},
        ylabel = { Normalized power (dB)},
        xlabel = {Time (ns)},
        width=3.15in,
        height=2.15in,
    ]
    \addplot+[no marks, domain=0:0.2,samples = 10] plot (\x, {10*log10(abs(exp(-2*\x/\TimeConst)-1))});
    % PLOT TO SHIFT:
    \addplot+[no marks, domain=0.2:3,samples = 50] plot
        (\x, {
            10 * log10 (abs( \finalCharge * exp(-2 * (x - 0.2) / \TimeConst) ))
            }
        );   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't really now know what the difference between `\x` and a regular `x` is, but you can also use `(\x - 0.2)` instead of `(x - 0.2)` if you want.

That's my output:
[image]

Comment: I didn't even think about doing this... shame on me. Thanks for the remark about \x!